# PL/SQL when no data found exception

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have a problem, I'm trying to resolve a trigger that have to check if an object is saved in a table.. But if i select the element who have the same cod object that i want to insert and this object does not exists in the table the trigger get me the exception no data found.. How i can do the insert if trigger get me no data found?

Can i do this?

```
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
INSERT INTO VALUES TABLE_X (:NEW.A,:NEW.B,:NEW.C)
```

Comment: Please post whatever code you have tried so far, with some input data and what the trigger is expected to do

Comment: @shrek i just want to know how can i evade the no data found exception.. Now i can not post the code because I am typing from smartphone

Comment: Try doing a count(*) check and if count(*) > 0, then the object/value exists and if count(*) = 0 then it does not.

Comment: The other option you can explore is using MERGE statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do.

Consider the following :

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE TABLE_X(A INT, B INT, C INT);

Table created
SQL> CREATE TABLE TABLE_Y(A INT, B INT, C INT);

Table created

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_bi_ins_y
  2  BEFORE INSERT ON TABLE_Y
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4  DECLARE
  5    V_A TABLE_Y.A%TYPE;
  6  BEGIN
  7   BEGIN
  8       SELECT Y.A
  9         INTO V_A
 10         FROM TABLE_Y Y
 11        WHERE Y.A = :NEW.A;
 12     EXCEPTION
 13      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
 14         INSERT INTO TABLE_X VALUES(:NEW.A,:NEW.B,:NEW.C);
 15   END;
 16  END;
 17  /

Trigger created

SQL> INSERT INTO TABLE_Y VALUES(1,0,0); 

1 row inserted

SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE_Y;

 A   B   C
--- --- ---
 1   0   0

SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE_X;

 A   B   C
--- --- ---
 1   0   0

-- the row with value 1 for column A does not exist, and insertion to TABLE_X occurs.

SQL> INSERT INTO TABLE_Y VALUES(1,1,1);

1 row inserted


SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE_Y;

 A   B   C
--- --- ---
 1   0   0
 1   1   1

SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE_X; 

 A   B   C
--- --- ---
 1   0   0

-- the row with value 1 for column A already exists, and no insertion occurs.
```